# How to properly use anonymous type with Netflix OData API

Tags: linq, odata, netflix

I am trying to use the query below in LINQPad.  It isnt working.  I am getting this exception:

> NotSupportedException: Constructing or initializing instances of the type <>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String] with the expression t.BoxArt.SmallUrl is not supported.

```
from t in Titles where t.Id == "ApUFq" select new { t.BoxArt.SmallUrl }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Netflix OData API, but your issue appears to be a common stumbling block with LINQ.

Try this instead:

```
from t in Titles
where t.Id == "ApUFq"
select new t.BoxArt.SmallUrl;
```

Or alternatively:

```
from t in Titles.Where(t0 => t0.Id == "ApUFq").ToArray()
select new { t.BoxArt.SmallUrl };
```

One or both should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The WCF Data Services client linq processor only supports projections which have member bind assignments. Which means that when you project out a field, you need to assign it to another field in the projected type.

NotSupportedException: Constructing or initializing instances of the type <>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String] with the expression t.BoxArt.SmallUrl is not supported.

`from t in Titles

  where t.Id == "ApUFq"

  select new { smallUrl = t.BoxArt.SmallUrl }`